# What is the right R-code for Tukeys HSD and Games-Howell Post hoc test?

Tags: r

I have done MANOVA analysis in R-Studio to evaluate whether there are significant differences in walnut characteristics among 12 cultivars. The R-code used and the results are:

```
MV_results <- manova(cbind(Wlength,Wwidth,Wthickness,Wweight,Sthickness,Sweight,Kweight) ~ walnuts$Cultivar, data = walnuts) 

summary.manova(MV_results)
                 Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df    Pr(>F)    
walnuts$Cultivar  1 0.39872   4.9261      7     52 0.0002541 ***
Residuals        58                                             
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I would like to do a post hoc test and a pairwise comparison using Tukeys HSD and Games-Howell test. What would be the appropriate r-code(s) to use? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Hello good people. Please advise/guide me in the above problem, I beg. In case something is not clear please let me know.